# Use "root" to install server and panel or install using another admin "user"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hosting

I have a website and some subdomains installed on Ubuntu server. I also have cron jobs running. webserver is OpenLiteSpeed and Panel is CyberPanel.

```
I have a "root" user.
And an admin "user" user, created as:

sudo adduser user
sudo adduser user sudo
usermod -aG sudo user
```

Everything is installed as "root" and working fine. I also require GUI, so I have installed KDE as "root" user and use "Chrome Remote Desktop" to connect to server as user "user", because "Chrome Remote Desktop" does not allow "root" users to connect.

The "user" user does not have access to folders created as "root" user, like folders belonging to my website root folders. It is not an issue, jut a small inconvenience.

My question is should I install webserver and panel as "root" or as "user". I mean should I create a "user" user, and then install webserver, panel, GUI with it? or with "root"?

Please note that I am not reselling any hosting etc. Just one website, some cron jobs, GUI and Chrome Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) should be considered.  Therefore only use `root` for tasks that your regular user can't do.

**Note** that whenever a user runs `sudo some-cmd` (without specifying a different username with the `sudo -u username`  option) that is effectively <sup>1</sup> the same as running that `some-cmd` as root.

> The "user" user does not have access to folders created as "root" user, like folders belonging to my website root folders. It is not an issue, jut a small inconvenience.

Then afterwards adjust the directory ownership and/or permissions so that your regular user can  place content where it needs to be placed...

---

1. There are some very subtle differences when logging in as root compared to the limited environment `sudo` sets up when executing a command.